# python3 loses connection to mysql connector during query

Tags: python, mysql, connector

I am running the latest version of python 3 with the latest connector/python for Mac OS from the Oracle MySQL site. But when I test the connection with the simple commands in a python script file:

```
import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='spUser', password='123',
                          host='127.0.0.1',
                          database='stellapeers_v2')
cnx.close()
```

I get the following errors, where the most important line is the final one that says :

*"mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2013: Lost Connection to MySQL Server during query"*

I have found many complaints about this issue on Google but no actual resolution.

Has anyone found out what the problem is and how to fix it?

Thank you

Here is the entire error output:

[image]

Comment: Is your mysql server accepting connections? And also, can you ping '127.0.0.1'?

Comment: Yes, the mysql server is working fine, I can start a mysql interactive session and run commands. And yes 127.0.0.1 is working fine.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-lost-connection.html. I've seen it happen when creating gigantic transactions, so I had to split things up into several ones.

Comment: and check the `connection_timeout` in your mysql config.